# How to emulate -webkit-device-pixel-ratio in web browser?

Tags: android

When developing apps for different Android phones, the different values of -webkit-device-pixel-ratio make life suck. I wonder if there is some extension or emulator to emulate these values in web browser.

Comment: I doubt it, since you would have to know the DPI of the screen in question to be able to convert raw pixels, which I'm pretty sure you can't know reliably (e.g. via a Javascript API).